# Difference of behavior between libstdc++ and libc++: operator>> on bitset

Tags: c++, gcc, clang, std, std-bitset

Consider the following code:

```
#include <bitset>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::stringstream stream;
    std::bitset<1> bitset(1);
    std::cout<<"before = "<<bitset[0]<<std::endl;
    stream<<"4";
    stream>>bitset;
    std::cout<<"after = "<<bitset[0]<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Compiled under `g++` with `libstdc++`, the result is:

```
> g++ bitset_empty.cpp -o bitset_empty
> ./bitset_empty 
before = 1
after = 1
```

Compiled under `clang++` with `libc++`, the result is:

```
> clang++ -stdlib=libc++ bitset_empty.cpp -o bitset_empty
> ./bitset_empty 
before = 1
after = 0
```

Which one is right? Both (because of undefined behavior)? GCC? Clang?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From my understanding, libc++ is right here, but it's not the only correct behavior.

> N4140 §20.6.4 [bitset.operators]
>
> *Effects:* Extracts up to N characters from is. Stores these characters in a temporary object str of type `basic_string<charT,
>   traits>`, then evaluates the expression `x = bitset<N>(str)`.
>   Characters are extracted and stored until any of the following occurs:
>
> - N characters have been extracted and stored;
> - end-of-file occurs on the input sequence;
> - the next input character is neither `is.widen(’0’)` nor `is.widen(’1’)` (in which case the input character is not extracted).
>
> If no characters are stored in `str`, calls
>   `is.setstate(ios_base::failbit)` (which may throw `ios_base::failure`
>   (27.5.5.4))

It's important to note that `x = bitset<N>(str)` is not conditional. If `ios_base::failure` is not thrown, then that is the expression executed. And `bitset<N>(""s)` (that is, of an empty string) is `0`.

Thus, in my understanding, your `bitset` should be zeroed or the aforementioned exception should've been thrown.

If no exception is thrown, you may want to test if your operation was successful (by testing the returned stream).

Answer (score 3):

You should check whether

```
stream>>bitset;
```

succeeds. If it does not, you cannot count on the value of `bitset` after that.

```
#include <bitset>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::stringstream stream;
    std::bitset<1> bitset(1);
    std::cout<<"before = "<<bitset[0]<<std::endl;
    stream<<"4";
    if ( stream>>bitset )
    {
       std::cout<<"after = "<<bitset[0]<<std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
       std::cout << "Failed to restore bitset from stream.\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output using g++ 4.9.3:

```
before = 1
Failed to restore bitset from stream.
```